# Detener un evento javascript

Tags: javascript

Este código logra mover un elemento "hijo" junto al mouse, dentro de un elemento "etiqueta"
que esta con overflow: hidden;  **lo que quiero lograr es que cuando el mouse sale del elemento "etiqueta" los cálculos de posición en el estilo en linea del elemento "hijo" se detenga.** Si inspeccionan el elemento "hijo" verán que en su estilo en linea **el calculo de posición continua cuando mueves el mouse fuera de "etiqueta".**

```js
let hijo = document.querySelector('.hijo');
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');

//El metodo .getBoundingClientRect() nos da 
//la posicion de un elemento con respecto al viewport(en numeros).
// tomare la posicion constante del elemento .hijo 
const coords = hijo.getBoundingClientRect();
const j = coords.top; // estamos obteniendo la posicion top en numero
const k = coords.left;

// se aplica forEach para obtener posicion de cada movimiento del mouse
// se obtiene la posicion del mouse con la funcion  mover(e)
etiqueta.forEach(link => {
// mouseover dice que entro en elemento etiqueta
    link.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {
    hijo.classList.add("edd1");// solo agrega un class que le da color red

     window.addEventListener("mousemove",function mover(e){
// se calcula la posicion top y left del mouse al cual le restamos
// la posicion del elemento "hijo"; resultado: mouse y "hijo" juntos 
         let m = e.pageY ;
         let n = e.pageX ;

         let t = m - j;
         let l = n - k;
         hijo.style.top = t + "px";// se le agrega px al calculo;
         hijo.style.left = l + "px";
    }); 
    });

    link.addEventListener("mouseleave",() => {// mouseleave dice que salio del elemento etiqueta
    hijo.classList.remove("edd1"); // le quita un class, que le quita color red
    });
});
```

```css
/* simples etilos para delimitar los div's*/
.box{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.etiqueta{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
background: green;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.hijo{
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
}
.edd1{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspeccione el "hijo" y luego muevan el cursor, verán a que me refiero.

Comment: Es sencillo, como mismo agregas el evento a la ventana con  `window.addEventListener` pues cuando ocurra el `mouseLeave`, que remueves la clase, también remueve el evento con `removeEventListener`. Para ello separa la función `mover` y la agregas como `window.addEventListener("mousemove", mover)` y lo remueves como  `window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mover)`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Gracia!, me acostumbre a usar .add... y olvide que existe .remove...  jajaja y estaba intentando hacerlo con condicionales. Gracias!!! por tomarte el tiempo de leer todo eso.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Podrías ponerlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

ya publique esto en otra pregunta mía que era diferente, pero que tenia la respuesta dentro del código.**Bueno dejo esto para quien quiera ver como queda después de arreglar el código**

```js
let hijo = document.querySelector('.hijo');
let etiqueta = document.querySelectorAll('.etiqueta');
//El metodo .getBoundingClientRect() nos da 
//la posicion de un elemento con respecto al viewport(en numeros).
// tomare la posicion constante del elemento .hijo 
const coords = hijo.getBoundingClientRect();
const j = coords.top; 
// estamos obteniendo la posicion top en numero
const k = coords.left;

// se aplica forEach para obtener posicion de cada movimiento del //mouse
etiqueta.forEach(link => {
// se obtiene la posicion del mouse con la funcion  mover(e)
    function mover(e){
// se calcula la posicion top y left del mouse al cual le restamos
// la posicion del elemento "hijo"; resultado: mouse e "hijo" //juntos 
     let m = e.pageY ;
     let n = e.pageX ;

     let t = m - j;
     let l = n - k;
     hijo.style.top = t + "px"; // agregando px a los numeros
     hijo.style.left = l + "px";
    };
// mouseover dice que entro en elemento etiqueta
    link.addEventListener("mouseover",() => {
    hijo.classList.add("edd1");
  // solo agrega un class que le da color red

     window.addEventListener("mousemove",mover);
   // agrega el evento junto a la funcion 
    });

    link.addEventListener("mouseleave",() => {
    // mouseleave dice que salio del elemento etiqueta
    hijo.classList.remove("edd1"); 
  // le quita un class, que le quita color red
     window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mover);
   // remuev el evento
    });
});
```

```css
/* Simples estilos para delimitar los div*/
.box{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: solid 1px black;
}
.etiqueta{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
background: green;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
}
.hijo{
position: absolute;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
transform: scale(0) ; /*desaparece el elemento hijo*/
}
.edd1{
background-color: red;
transform: scale(1); /*aparece el elemento hijo*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="etiqueta">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```